# How to make an Op from a frozen TensorFlow graph?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

How can I make an Op out of a frozen TensorFlow graph?  The same trick, as done in TF Hub?

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128-with-normalization/1"
  embed = hub.Module(module_url)
  embeddings = embed(["A long sentence", "A sentence"])
```

The *embed*() from TF Hub can be used freely as a custom op, anywhere in the graph.  I'm looking for the same, only instead of module_url, use my own frozen graph, from a .pb file.  It's easy to add operations to the end of the imported graph, or edit the graph, but using an imported graph as a custom operation is much clearer.

I've looked at the TF Hub implementation, but it is not too concise. And it doesn't look like there is other sample code for that. Please, can someone give or point to better sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a hub.Module as above in the call to `embed(...)` brings in a whole subgraphgraph,  consisting of many TF ops. It just looks self-contained in the Python code because all the work is hidden in a single function call, but no custom ops are involved here.

Perhaps your needs can be met by creating your own hub.Module? It's not hard, see [tensorflow.org/hub/creating](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/creating), and you can just use it from your filesystem.

There are older examples around how to use `tf.import_meta_graph()` (which includes the collections of the `tf.Graph` and supports checkpointed variables) or the even more basic `tf.import_graph_def()` (commonly used with frozen graph defs, e.g., in [label_image.py](http://tensorflow/examples/label_image)), but hub.Module handles many of the gaps and subtle issues in these older approaches for you.